# Error while installing pandas using anaconda's jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, python-import

I installed pandas using anaconda prompt.
using the following command:-

```
pip install pandas
```

and get the following message:-

```
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in c:\users\maini_\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (1.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.13.3 in c:\users\maini_\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (1.18.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.2 in c:\users\maini_\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (2020.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.6.1 in c:\users\maini_\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\maini_\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.6.1->pandas) (1.15.0)
```

But when I import it in the Jupiter notebook using the following command:-

```
import pandas as pd
```

I get the following error:-

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-3-7dd3504c366f> in <module>
    ----> 1 import pandas as pd

    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py in <module>
         30 
         31 try:
    ---> 32     from pandas._libs import hashtable as _hashtable, lib as _lib, tslib as _tslib
         33 except ImportError as e:  # pragma: no cover
         34     # hack but overkill to use re

    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\__init__.py in <module>
          1 # flake8: noqa
          2 
    ----> 3 from .tslibs import (
          4     NaT,
          5     NaTType,

    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\tslibs\__init__.py in <module>
          1 # flake8: noqa
          2 
    ----> 3 from .conversion import localize_pydatetime, normalize_date
          4 from .nattype import NaT, NaTType, iNaT, is_null_datetimelike
          5 from .np_datetime import OutOfBoundsDatetime

    pandas\_libs\tslibs\conversion.pyx in init pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion()

    AttributeError: type object 'pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion._TSObject' has no attribute '__reduce_cython__'
```

I also tried this command

```
python -m pip install pandas
```

and get the following message

```
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in c:\users\maini_\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (1.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.13.3 in c:\users\maini_\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (1.18.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.6.1 in c:\users\maini_\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.2 in c:\users\maini_\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (2020.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\maini_\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.6.1->pandas) (1.15.0)
```

Please help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The easiest way to get a working pandas installation in an anaconda environment on a windows computer is arguably `pip uninstall pandas` followed by `conda install pandas`. If you are using notebook with anaconda, I can also recommend using `%conda install <pkg-name>` right inside the notebook.

Comment: Yes, It worked. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Anaconda, the best way is to use the anaconda prompt:

```sh
conda install pandas
```